# Error while Exporting from Google Earth

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, sentinel-5p

I was trying to find a time series chart of **SO2** in my region of interest. But after generating the chart I find it difficult to export to drive.
Here is my [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7e2860a5a3a8bddaea4370252310f5ba)

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Please do not use ALL CAPS in titles. It is interpreted as "shouting" and downvoted.

Comment: I think that It's a good idea to post the code here.  Being a link, it could disappear.  Also,  one needs an account to view it.

Answer (score 1):

Your export statement needs to be edited. You created an image collection with `mol_to_ton`. When you want to export an image collection, it needs to be changed to bands with `toBands()`. In your case, change:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
image: mol_to_ton,
description: 'SO2_march_SI_2019',
folder: 'GEE',
fileNamePrefix: 'SO2_change',
region: state,
fileFormat: 'GEOTIFF',
scale: 1000
});
```

to

```
Export.image.toDrive({
image: mol_to_ton.toBands(),
description: 'SO2_march_SI_2019',
folder: 'GEE',
fileNamePrefix: 'SO2_change',
region: state,
fileFormat: 'GEOTIFF',
scale: 1000
});
```

You can use the statement in the original form if it's just one image.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer and it worked, but when I tried to open the exported image in QGIS. It appears as black color box.

Comment: @pooja if the answer works, please Accept it by marking the check box next to answer that has the Accept label. Please also add the code to your post as suggested in one of the comments. StackOverflow rules include one question per post. If your output is incorrect, you should make another question to ask for help with that.